# will webservice helps to Pass PHP Session one site to other site

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, nusoap

Please any one tell me will webservice using nusoap helps to Pass PHP Session one site to other site. I need to pass the user session to my other site using PHP/Ajax/SOAP call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy with a callback (here we have `server1` as origin, as `server2` as server to redirect to):

- From `server1`, redirect user to http://server2/auth_from_server1.php?id=12345
- On `server2` (internally, in the PHP code of `auth_from_server1.php`), do a request to http://server1/secret/check_session_id.php with the ID, 12345.
- On `server1`, in the implementation of `check_session_id.php`, validate the ID and return OK, FAILURE, and session related data you want to pass, such as username, ...
- On `server2`, when the call returns with OK, store the transferred session data, and give the user a cookie and session for this server.

Answer (score 0):

Depends... If you use cookies to send the sessionid from the user to the server, no. Since the browser won't send the cookie to a different domain than what it was originated from.

You can however send the sessionID as a parameter in the ajax call. But this will only work if the other site have access to the session data. Eg. same server and session data is in /tmp